# Elasticsearch - Limiting allocation of shards

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've read a number of articles / forums on the placing of indexes/shards but have not yet found a solution to my requirement.

Fundamentally, I want to use Logstash (+ Elasticsearch/Kibana) to build  a globally distributed cluster, but I want to limit the placement of primary and replica shards to be local to the region they were created in to reduce WAN traffic, but I also want to be able to query all data as a single dataset.

## Example

Let's say I have two ES nodes in UK (uknode1/uknode2), and two in US (usnode1/usnode2).
If Logstash sends some data to usnode1, I want it to place the replica on usnode2, and *not* send this across the WAN to the uknode* nodes.

I've tried playing around with index and routing allocation settings, but cannot stop the shards being distributed across all 4 nodes.  It's slightly complicated by the fact that index names are dynamically built based on the "type" but that's another challenge for a later date.  Even with one index, I can't work this it.

I could split this into two separate clusters but I want to be able to query all nodes as a single dataset (via Kibana) so I don't think that is a valid option at this stage as Kibana can only query one cluster.

Is this even possible to achieve?

The reason I ask if this is possible is what would happen if I write to an index called "myTest" on UK node, and the same index on a US node.....as this is ultimately the same index and I'm not sure how ES would handle this.

So if anyone has any suggestions, or just to say "not possible", that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [possible](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html#shard-allocation-filtering), but not recommended. Elasticsearch needs reliable data connection between nodes in the cluster to function, which is difficult to ensure for geographically distributed cluster. A better solution would be to have two clusters, one in UK and another one in US. If you need to search both of them at the same time you can use [tribal node](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-tribe.html#modules-tribe).

Comment: THanks, the tribal node is the way to go.  I'll post a more detailed answer to my problem on how I used this great new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  I looked into this a bit more and have the solution which is indeed using tribal nodes.

For anyone who isn't familiar with them, this is a new feature in ES 1.0.0+

What you do is allocate a new ES node as a tribe node, and configure it to connect to all your other clusters, and when you run a query against it, it queries all clusters and returns a consolidated set of results from all of them.

So in my scenario, I have two distinct clusters, one in each region something this.

**US Region**

`cluster.name: us-region`

Two nodes in this region called `usnode1` and `usnode2`

Both nodes are master/data nodes

**UK Region**

`cluster.name: uk-region`

Two nodes in this region called `uknode1` and `uknode2`

Both nodes are master/data nodes

The you create another ES node and add some configuration to make it a Tribe node.

Edit `elasticsearch.yml` with something like this :

`node.data: false
    node.master: false
    tribe.blocks.write: false
    tribe.blocks.metadata: false
    tribe.t1.cluster.name: us-region
    tribe.t1.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["usnode1","usnode2"]
    tribe.t2.cluster.name: uk-region
    tribe.t2.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["uknode1","uknode2"]`

You then point Kibana to the tribe node and it worked brilliantly - excellent feature.

Kibana dashboards still save, although I'm not sure how it picks which cluster to save to   yet but seems to address my question so a bit more playing and I think it I'll have it sorted.

Comment: One thing I've since found (and is documented if you read thoroughly) is that if two clusters have the same index name, the tribe node will pick only one of them (by default) and will not aggregate the two indexes into one data set. 

So a limitation here, and we will get round it by prefixing the index name with the region to make them unique. Not ideal, but still meets the desired state.